# working with urlencode and GET keeping user values in PHP form

Tags: php, forms, urlencode

Building a PHP form for searching. When a user submits the form, the form input field converts to urlencoded value.

Issue - When user inputs - `mango cherry` into search filed and form is submitted, search field changes to `mango+cherry`.

HTML Form

```
<form action = <?php url_echo('/task/task.php') ?>  method ='get'>
<div class='row' >
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="clientname">Client Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="clientname" name="clientname" value="<?php echo h_url( h($_GET['clientname']) ); ?>">
    </div>    
</div>
<div class="row">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Search" >
</div>
</form>
```

PHP

```
function h($str_to_encode) {
    return htmlspecialchars ($str_to_encode);
}
function h_url($str_to_encode) {
    return urlencode($str_to_encode);
}
```

Using GET, as I want the URL to include the search parameter. This is a simplified form, I have many more fields. I am learning PHP and very new to best practices to be followed. I am open to changing entire approach of form submission.

Comment: why do you need to encode? you really don't need to, btw, your input text is missing the name attribute

Comment: @Ghost form submission automatically converts URL into `urlencoding`?

Comment: yes since you set your method as GET (in your form), that behavior is normal, and you don't need to urldecode encode it, just read the GET array as is, no need to do fancy stuff

Comment: Tried it. Perfect. This solves my Question. Please also post this as an answer, I will mark it as the correct answer.